# DFS return from vertex proof

Tags: graph-theory

How can I prove or disprove that - for any directed graph - when DFS visits a vertex u, then every undiscovered vertex v such that u has a path to v must be discovered before DFS returns from u?

Comment: There seems to be some missing context here.  In asking if a vertex $v$ "must be discovered  before DFS returns from $u$" one must surely have in mind a more substantial description of the algorithm.  Depth-first search describes a style of searching (e.g. as compared to breadth-first search) but in applying it to an arbitrary "directed graph", some details must be supplied.

Comment: @hardmath Sorry to be vague. I only mean the standard DFS algorithm. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search pseudo-code)

Comment: The illustration of that Wikipedia article shows a rooted tree, not an arbitrary directed graph.  Hence my confusion.

Comment: @hardmath the directed graph is arbitrary. I have since updated my question so as to make it open to the possibility that it is disprovable, because we are talking about an arbitrary directed graph. I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: I suspect that you have in mind a kind of "follow your nose" algorithm such as is often proposed for finding a path from one vertex to another.  But it still needs clarification.  Perhaps for your purpose it will be enough to meditate on what you expect to happen if a directed cycle leads from $u$ back to itself?  Do we loop forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the directed graph with vertices $\{\, a,b,c \,\}$ and edges

$$ \{\, (a,b), (b,a), (a,c)\,\}.$$

Suppose DFS starts from $a$ and visits $b$ before $c$.  Though $c$ is reachable from $b$, when DFS pulls back from $b$, $c$ is still unvisited.

The property, on the other hand, holds when $u$ is a DFS source, that is, one of the vertices from which the search starts.   Let's prove it.

Aiming for a contradiction, suppose the set $C$ of vertices that are reachable from $u$ and remain undiscovered when DFS returns from $u$ is not empty.

Let $v$ be a vertex in $C$ and consider a path from $u$ to $v$.  Such a path, which exists because $v$ is reachable from $u$, has one end that is discovered, namely $u$, and one end that is not discovered, namely $v$.

Therefore there is at least one edge along the path that connects a discovered node $u'$ to an undiscovered node $v'$.  This is impossible, though, because after discovering $u'$, DFS must discover $v'$.  Hence $C$ must be empty.

Note how we relied on the assumption that the visit from $u'$ must have terminated before the one from $u$.  This is not true in the example above.

Another condition that guarantees the property is restricting it to vertices that are reachable from $u$ along paths that only go through unvisited vertices.  This guarantees that the visit of $u'$ terminates before that of $u$.